# Subscription in Component not receiving values from shared service Observable

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components

I have this service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Injectable()
export class MissionService {
    // Observable string sources
    private missionAnnouncedSource = new Subject<string>();
    private missionConfirmedSource = new Subject<string>();
    // Observable string streams
    missionAnnounced$ = this.missionAnnouncedSource.asObservable();
    missionConfirmed$ = this.missionConfirmedSource.asObservable();
    // Service message commands
    announceMission(mission: string) {
        this.missionAnnouncedSource.next(mission);
    }
    confirmMission(astronaut: string) {
        this.missionConfirmedSource.next(astronaut);
    }
}
```

This component:

```
export class ComponentOne {
    constructor(private service: MissionService) { }

    onClick() {
        console.log('entered in the onclick method');
        this.service.announceMission('mission started');
        this.service.missionAnnounced$.subscribe(response => console.log('from component 1: ' + response), error => console.log('error: ', error))
    }
}
```

This other component:

```
   export class ComponentTwo {
        constructor(private service: MissionService) {
        console.log('entered in constructor ComponentTwo')
            this.service.missionAnnounced$.subscribe(response => console.log('from component 2: ' + response),
                error => console.log('error: ', error));
        }
    }
```

I don't know why the `console.log` inside `subscribe()`  with the value of the response on `ComponentTwo` is never printed, even the part of the message `from component 2:` is never showing up. However the message `entered in constructor ComponentTwo` is always showing up.. There is not any error message showing up neither

Comment: Do you have more than one provider for the service (for example, do you include it in the `providers` list of each component)? There should be only one global provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a `Subject`, you will only receive notifications of events (values) that are emitted subsequent to you calling `subscribe`. In this case, I suspect that the service is emitting its value before the subscription in `ComponentTwo` has been created.

If you want the Subject to "remember" its last value, so that new subscribers will see the last value, see for example [BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html).

Another possibility is that you are providing the service to both components independently, in which case you will actually have two distinct instances of your service. This would mean that events emitted on the service associated with `ComponentOne` will not be seen by `ComponentTwo`, and vice-versa.

In order for two components to share the same instance of a provider, it should normally be provided in an @NgModule containing them both (and specifically *not* listed in two places, one for each Component). For example:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ComponentOne, ComponentTwo],
  providers: [MissionService],  // Will be shared by both components
  // ...
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the [share](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-share) operator works.

> An Observable that upon connection causes the source Observable to emit items to its Observers.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
...
missionAnnounced$ = this.missionAnnouncedSource.asObservable().share();
missionConfirmed$ = this.missionConfirmedSource.asObservable().share();
```